# When parsing JSONArray comes last in the list of Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, retrofit

I get json request through GET

```
{"data": [
    "Черногория",
    "Чехия",
    "Чили"
]}
```

How to parse it if you need to display each country in a separate item. I'm using Pojo.

```
@SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<String> data = null;
```

this is an activity in which I use retrofit to connect, everything comes, but displays only the last field in the lists

```
public void onResponse(Call<Countries> call, Response<Countries> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                Countries countries = response.body();
                if (countries != null) {
                    for (int x =0; x<countries.getData().size(); x++) {
                        arrayList.add(countries);
                        viewAdapterCountry.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }}}
        }
```

this adapter

```
private ArrayList<Countries> countryModels;
    Countries countryModel = countryModels.get(i);
            List<String> country = countryModel.getData();
            for (int x = 0; x<country.size(); x++){
                viewHolder.button.setText(country.get(x));
            }
```

Comment: aren't you always overwriting the button text with `viewHolder.button.setText(country.get(x));` so the last entry in your list is the one you see?

Comment: do this, viewHolder.button.setText(country.toString());  displays everything, but not in each button, but all in one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are adding all the data at once instead of one by one 
`arrayList.add(countries);`you should do  `arrayList.add(countries.getData().get(x));` then outside the loop you should write `viewAdapterCountry.notifyDataSetChanged();`

in bindivewholder of adapter

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = list?.get(position)

        holder.button.setText(item)

    }
```